# SQL query taking too long - multiple ANDs with the same ID

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am not sure why but this query (even when there are two results) is taking too long to execute.

What I am trying to do is that `users c` table's UID (primary key) matches with `entity_id` of all the other tables (foreign key). That's all I have to do.

I guess the problem is that there are too many foreign keys I have to match my primary key.

```
SELECT
              f.field_fmno_value as fo,
              fn.field_full_name_value as fullname,
              c.mail as email,
              t.field_type_value as persontype,
              ti.field_title_value as persontitle,
              sc.field_skill_code_value as skillcode,
              sg.field_skill_group_value as skillgroup,
              dn.field_department_value as deptt,
              r.field_region_for_real_value as region,
              cl.field_region_value as citylocation,
              goc.field_goc_office_value as goc,
              hu.field_hub_value as hub,            
              ge.field_gender_value as gender,
              ft.field_full_tenure_value as tenure,
              tsa.field_tenure_since_associate_value as tass,
              b.category as category,
              b.subcategory as subcategory,
              b.section as industry,
              b.title as title,

              a.browser_platform, b.path, b.title, a.referer, a.time, a.id
            FROM
              track_da_files a, track_da_files_paths b, users c, field_data_field_region_for_real r,
              field_data_field_fo f,
              field_data_field_full_name fn,
              field_data_field_type t,
              field_data_field_title ti,
              field_data_field_s_code sc,
              field_data_field_s_group sg,
              field_data_field_department dn,
              field_data_field_region cl,
              field_data_field_g_office goc,
              field_data_field_hub hu,
              field_data_field_gender ge,
              field_data_field_full_ten ft,
              field_data_field_ten_since_associate tsa

            where a.pid = b.pid AND a.uid = c.uid AND a.uid <> 0
            AND c.uid = r.entity_id
            AND c.uid = fn.entity_id
            AND c.uid = f.entity_id
            AND c.uid = t.entity_id
            AND c.uid = ti.entity_id
            AND c.uid = sc.entity_id
            AND c.uid = sg.entity_id
            AND c.uid = dn.entity_id
            AND c.uid = cl.entity_id
            AND c.uid = goc.entity_id
            AND c.uid = hu.entity_id
            AND c.uid = ge.entity_id
            AND c.uid = ft.entity_id
            AND c.uid = tsa.entity_id

            GROUP a.pid
            ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Please add to your question (1) table definitions for your tables, and (b) an explain plan for your query. Also, (3) how long does it take to execute on your hardware, and (4) what sort of time would be acceptable? The solutions offered may depend on whether you're looking for a 10% speedup or 90%.

Comment: As a starting point, I'd change some of those `WHERE` clauses into ANSI-style joins - I imagine it would help the database optimiser to understand what is a filter and what is a join proper.

Comment: Thanks haifer, I added details to my question.

Comment: I've suggested four things that might be helpful, could you add those in? An ERD might not be essential, but the explain plan is. You need to ask the database why it is slow, and readers can't do that without your exact database in front of them.

Comment: Is there a way you could assist with the join?

Comment: One failure is you have "GROUP" instead of "GROUP BY"... is that failing your command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised query to JOIN format... Also, GROUP BY appears irrelevant as you are not doing any aggregations.  If you have multiple records possible at any of the child-level tables, that could force multiple records, but only for those instances.  If everything is a 1:1 ratio of records, you should be fine.  If 1:n ration in more than 1 child table you will get a Cartesian result and could bloat (such as multiple skill groups).

Also, since a.uid = c.uid, you could also use the a.uid to all the underlying tables too so they all appear as child-tables.  I would assume all these child tables are lookup tables and ALL of them have an index on the respective field representing the "uid" it is joined based on.

```
SELECT
      f.field_fmno_value as fo,
      fn.field_full_name_value as fullname,
      c.mail as email,
      t.field_type_value as persontype,
      ti.field_title_value as persontitle,
      sc.field_skill_code_value as skillcode,
      sg.field_skill_group_value as skillgroup,
      dn.field_department_value as deptt,
      r.field_region_for_real_value as region,
      cl.field_region_value as citylocation,
      goc.field_goc_office_value as goc,
      hu.field_hub_value as hub,            
      ge.field_gender_value as gender,
      ft.field_full_tenure_value as tenure,
      tsa.field_tenure_since_associate_value as tass,
      b.category as category,
      b.subcategory as subcategory,
      b.section as industry,
      b.title as title,
      a.browser_platform, 
      b.path, 
      b.title, 
      a.referer, 
      a.time, 
      a.id
   FROM
      track_da_files a
         JOIN track_da_files_paths b
            ON a.pid = b.pid 
         JOIN users c
            ON a.uid = c.uid
         JOIN field_data_field_region_for_real r
            ON a.uid = r.entity_id
         JOIN field_data_field_fo f
            ON a.uid = f.entity_id
         JOIN field_data_field_full_name fn
            ON a.uid = fn.entity_id
         JOIN field_data_field_type t,
            ON a.uid = t.entity_id
         JOIN field_data_field_title ti,
            ON a.uid = ti.entity_id
         JOIN field_data_field_s_code sc,
            ON a.uid = sc.entity_id
         JOIN field_data_field_s_group sg,
            ON a.uid = sg.entity_id
         JOIN field_data_field_department dn,
            ON a.uid = dn.entity_id
         JOIN field_data_field_region cl,
            ON a.uid = cl.entity_id
         JOIN field_data_field_g_office goc,
            ON a.uid = goc.entity_id
         JOIN field_data_field_hub hu,
            ON a.uid = hu.entity_id
         JOIN field_data_field_gender ge,
            ON a.uid = ge.entity_id
         JOIN field_data_field_full_ten ft,
            ON a.uid = ft.entity_id
         JOIN field_data_field_ten_since_associate tsa
            ON a.uid = tsa.entity_id
   where 
      a.uid <> 0
   GROUP BY
      a.pid
   ORDER BY 
      1 DESC
```

One final possibility on this query under MySQL is

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      f.field_fmno_value as fo ...(rest of query).
```

STRAIGHT_JOIN tells MySQL to do the query in the table order I provided since everything looks like a child lookup, you want the driving table to be the primary "a" table reference.

Comment: It works great. One small gripe. It is only showing distinct rows. Any possible to show all rows?

Comment: @Steve, Remove the GROUP BY clause